# On Marsden's 'Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry' Exercise 5.3-4. (fubini study form is closed)

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry, quotient-spaces, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In exercise 5.3-4. in Marsden's book I'm asked to

> prove that $\mathbf d \Omega^{fs} = 0$ on $\mathbb P \mathcal H$ directly,

where $\mathbb P \mathcal H$ is an arbitrary projective Hilbert space (possibly infinite dimensional) endowed with the *fubini-study form* $\Omega^{fs}$. He already proved this using the invariance of $\Omega^{fs}$ under the action of $\mathbb P U(\mathcal H)$, which I'm not allowed to use.

The symplectic form on $\mathcal H$ is given as
$$\Omega(\varphi_1, \varphi_2) := -2 \, \mathrm {Im} \, \left<\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \right>,$$and there is also the natural projection $$\pi: \mathcal H \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb P \mathcal H,\; \psi \mapsto [\psi] := \mathbb C \psi,$$ with its associated tangent map $$T\pi: \left\{
\begin{align}
&\mathcal T(\mathcal H \setminus \{0\}) &&\to T(\mathbb P \mathcal H)\\
 &\varphi \in \mathcal T_{\psi}(\mathcal H \setminus \{0\}) &&\mapsto \varphi + [\psi] \in T_{[\psi]}(\mathbb P \mathcal H) \cong \mathcal H \,/\, \mathbb C \psi.
\end{align}\right.$$

On p. 155 in Marsden's book the *Fubini study form* on $\mathbb P \mathcal H$ was defined in terms of the symplectic form  on $\mathcal H$ as follows:

> For $[\psi] \in \mathbb P \mathcal H$, $\|\psi\| = 1,$ and $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in (\mathbb C \psi)^{\bot}$,
> $$\Omega^{fs}_{[\psi]}(T_{\psi}\pi(\varphi_1), T_{\psi}\pi(\varphi_2))  := \Omega(\varphi_1, \varphi_2).$$

This looks like a *pushforward* under the natural projection $\pi_{\mathcal S} : \mathcal S \to \mathbb P \mathcal H$, from the unit sphere $\mathcal S = \{ \psi \in \mathcal H \mid \|\psi\|^2 = 1\}$ onto $\mathbb P \mathcal H$, i.e. $\Omega^{fs} = {\pi_{\mathcal S}}_* \Omega$. But of course it isn't since $\pi_{\mathcal S}$ is not injective. And hence ${\pi_{\mathcal S}}_* \Omega$ is not even defined (under the inverse image of $T\pi$ both arguments might end up in different tangent spaces). That's a real bummer because I already managed to show that $\mathbf d \Omega = 0$. Using this result I now just need a justification so that I can say

> For $[\psi] \in \mathbb P \mathcal H$, $\|\psi\| = 1,$ and $\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3 \in (\mathbb C \psi)^{\bot}$,
> $$\mathbf d \Omega^{fs}_{[\psi]}(T_{\psi}\pi(\varphi_1), T_{\psi}\pi(\varphi_2), T_{\psi}\pi(\varphi_3)) = \mathbf d \Omega(\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3).$$

But how can I do that? Thanks in advance for any hints / suggestions.